# Create searchbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use an Access database to manage employee information. I want to create a search box, so that when I enter the employee id the rest of the information could be filled automatically.

I created a function to try to get each column's value and assign it when I click the button, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```vb
Public Function GetEmployeeName() As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set GetEmployeeName = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("select EmployeeName From EInfor where EmployeeID = " & txtEID.Value)
End Function

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    txtEmployeeName = GetEmployeeName()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that `GetEmployeeName()` should return the `EmployeeName` which matches a given `EmployeeID`.  In that case, you don't need a `Recordset`.  A `DLookup` expression can give you what you need.

```vb
Public Function GetEmployeeName(ByVal pEID As Long) As Variant
    GetEmployeeName = DLookup("EmployeeName", "EInfor", "EmployeeID=" & pEID)
End Function
```

That function expects you to supply the target `EmployeeID` as a parameter, so it is not hard-wired to the value of a control on one particular form.

If no matching `EmployeeName` is found, the function returns Null.  In your command button's click event, you can use `Nz()` to substitute something else for Null.

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Me!txtEmployeeName.Value = Nz(GetEmployeeName(Me!txtEID.Value), "unknown")
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your very useful advices, it works well

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the default property of `txtEmployeeName` (which is the `Value` property) to `GetEmployeeName()` which returns an `ADODB.Recordset` which has the default property `Fields`, which is a collection.

This can't possibly work.

Try this instead:

```
txtEmployeeName = GetEmployeeName().Fields(0)
```

---

If you want to update multiple textboxes you should consider only using one SELECT statement to retrieve all needed values at once:

```
"select * From EInfor where EmployeeID = " & CLng(txtEID.Value)
```

And then you can update the textboxes like this:

```
txtEmployeeName    = rst.Fields("EmployeeName")
txtEmployeeBoss    = rst.Fields("EmployeeBoss")
txtEmployeeAddress = rst.Fields("EmployeeAddress")
txtEmployeeSalary  = rst.Fields("EmployeeSalary")
```

Note the following changes:

- Using `CLng()` I made sure that only a number can be passed in the SQL code (this is a security vulnerability, see [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) for an example).
- I merged the two procedures you have: Put everything in `btnSearch_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ComboBox that filters the record set as you type.  This is very useful when you are searching for records that are similar to what you are looking for but may not be an exact match!

Hit Alt+F11 and right click the form you created before.  Paste in the script below.

```
[![Option Compare Database

Private Sub ComboSelect_Change()

    '  You need to use String delimiters if you want to use a Text Field like:
    '  Me.Filter "\[ATextFieldInRecordSource\] = """ & Me.FilterComboBox & """"

    '  For a Numeric Field, use something like this:
    '  Me.Filter "\[ANumericFieldInRecordSource\] = " & Me.FilterComboBox
    '  Me.FilterOn = True

    Me.\[Customer_Query subform1\].Form.Filter = "\[Company_Name\] Like '*" &
                     Replace(Me.ComboSelect.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
    Me.\[Customer_Query subform1\].Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub][1]][1]



Notice a few things:
•   The subform is named Customer_Query subform1’
•   The combobox is named ComboSelect’
•   Finally, the ‘like clause’ is used in combination with the wildcard character.
•   Like '*" & Replace(Me.ComboSelect.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
```

When you type text into the combobox, the results in the subform are dynamically re-queried.